# Storing users token and Secret (3rd party)

Tags: azure, security, .net-core, secret-key

I am working on the Application (MyApp), which needs to store end users' tokens/secrets and I am reluctant to store end users' tokens/secrets in a Database.

Each end user provides 3rd Party tokens/secret to MyApp. Such user's token/secret enables my App to access 3rd party API on behalf of each end user. Each user can grant access to many 3rd party apps.

Simplified workflow is below

[image]

1. User Gets Token and Secret via 3rd Party GUI.
2. User grants MyApp to use 3rd Party API by providing 3rdParty Token and Secret (user will enter 3rdParty Token and Secret via MyApp Web GUI )
3. My App should store Users Token/Secret in "SECURE PERSISTENT STORAGE" to make sure that after app restart, it still can access 3Rd party API on behalf of the end user X.
4. MyApp can perform actions on behalf of user X Using 3rd Party API by providing user’s X Token and Secret

I am looking for implementation of "Secure storage" suitable for storing/retrieving thousands end user's tokens/secrets accessible via via .NET Core (C#).

I think the only way is to store encrypted tokens/secrets in some storage. I have considered my own database as last options as I am not security expert.

I have checked Azure Vault, but it is mainly designed for "secure store application credentials such as secrets, keys, and certificates", but I am looking for secure storage of user' data.

I am struggling to find ready to use "secure storage". I am sure that I am missing something and there is ready to use solution out there.

I have checked many SO topics and most of them are addressing another issues like:
a) storing "app credentials for accessing DataStorage": e.g. accessing Database
b) Storing end user credentials for my own application

I deal with those 2 above issues as well and I use:
a) Azure Vault for storing "app credentials for accessing Relational database"
b) Storing end user credentials (end user username and password to access mu own MyApp) in Azure AD B2C

How do you store users sensitive data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what it is about Key Vault that doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure Azure KeyVault is suitable for storing/retrieving thousands end user's tokens/secrets.

Comment: It has no problems handling thousands of secrets. What is your specific concern?

Comment: Matt, thank you for answering. If thousands of secrets are not an issue I will use it. I have implemented in the meantime storing encrypted tokens/secrets in my own DB, but is it not in proction and I am not security guru I will rather go for Azure Vault.